# How to save customer custom attribute default value to all Customers

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I created a custom attribute for the customer entity. I also have the `adminhtml_customer` form, where the value can be changed and `saved`.

The problem which I am facing is that, by default for all the customers the custom attribute is not present.

Only once I save it through the admin panel, that it appears as the data for that customer.

So, is there any way I can set a default value for the customer custom attribute which is not there itself by default.

The code which I used to make custom attribute :

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$entityTypeId     = (int)$installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = (int)$installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = (int)$installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute( $entityTypeId, 'whatsapp_status', array(
    'type'               => 'int',
    'label'              => 'Whatsapp Status',
    'input'              => 'select',
    'forms'              => array('adminhtml_customer'),
    'source'             => 'dbaux_customer/source_whatsappOption',
    'required'           => false,
    'visible'            => 1,
    'default'            => 'Inactive',
    'system'             => 0,
    'user_defined'       => 1,
    'nullable'           => false,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'whatsapp_status',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'whatsapp_status');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$oAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

My Source File :

```
<?php
class Dbaux_Customer_Model_Source_WhatsappOption extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("New User"),
                    "value" =>  0
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Opted In"),
                    "value" =>  1
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Opted Out"),
                    "value" =>  2
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Not Registered"),
                    "value" =>  3
                ),

            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option["value"] == $value) {
                return $option["label"];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice a typo in your installation script. **You were trying to save a string, `option label` (varchar) as a default value for the customer entity attribute (`whatsapp_status`) of type integer, instead of the `option value`**.

You should save 0 or 1. In your case, if you want to set Inactive as the default value for the given attribute, you should set the default value as 0. Cross check your source class file `dbaux_customer/source_whatsappOption` to confirm the respective option values for the options.

So it should be like this, which will set the inactive status as default for all the customers.

```
$installer->addAttribute( $entityTypeId, 'whatsapp_status', array(
    'type'               => 'int',
    'label'              => 'Whatsapp Status',
    'input'              => 'select',
    'forms'              => array('adminhtml_customer'),
    'source'             => 'dbaux_customer/source_whatsappOption',
    'required'           => false,
    'visible'            => 1,
    'default'            => 0,
    'system'             => 0,
    'user_defined'       => 1,
    'nullable'           => false,
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even when I did change the default to 0, it behaves the same way, with no attribute created for each customer until we save them specifically. I have added my source file code for reference.
Please do tell where I am going wrong if possible.